# TagHelpers not being processed in views other than _Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I load a page and when I use a custom Layout it appears that the `_ViewImports` file may not being applied. Not sure how to troubleshoot this. If I set `Layout = _Layout`, the asp- tags work just fine (specifically `asp-append-version`). So it's not how I'm calling the view or the layout in my view. Nothing else changes except the name of the Layout I want.

It was my understanding that `_ViewImports` is loaded before any Layout that is specified and it gets applied globally. Also, from what I can tell, there is nothing special at the beginning of the `_Layouts` file that would force the loading of `_ViewImports` (especially considering I put any directives at the top of my `_Layouts` into `_CustomLayout` and I still got the same behavior).

I am using ASP.NET Core 1.1. Does anyone have any similar experiences and/or fixes? I'm sort of stumped.

Comment: Where is your custom layout? I create a layout which is located in `Views->Shared`, change the layout for Home/Contact like `Layout = "_CustomLayout";`, the tag helpers works. You may share us the steps to reproduce

Comment: Yeah. That is where mine is as well; in shared. So I'm not really sure how to "reproduce" anything. All I'm doing is this: `@{ Layout = "_ReportPdfLayout" }` There is nothing else at the top of my file other than a `@model`.

Comment: Could you share us your project which could reproduce your issue?